# Trying to Create publishing page using JSOM Sharepoint 2013 and changing page layout

Tags: sharepoint

Hi I am Trying to Create publishing page using JSOM Sharepoint 2013 and changing page layout. My code runs without errors but doesn't change the page layout or any other page field e.g. 'Page Title'

Here is my code

```
'use strict';

var context = new SP.ClientContext('/sites/poc');
//var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

// Variables used in various callbacks 

var web;
var pubWeb;
var pageInfo;
var newPage;
var listItem;
//var hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
//var appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
$(document).ready(function () {

    web = context.get_web();
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    $('#CreatePage').click(function () { createPage(); });
});

function createPage() {
    context.load(web);
    context.executeQueryAsync(

        // Success callback after loading the App Web. 
        // We first want to get the host web, and cast it as a PublishingWeb. 
        function () {
            var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
            var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostUrl);
            web = hostcontext.get_web();

            pubWeb = SP.Publishing.PublishingWeb.getPublishingWeb(context, web);
            context.load(web);
            context.load(pubWeb);
            context.executeQueryAsync(

                // Success callback after getting the host Web as a PublishingWeb. 
                // We now want to add a new Publishing Page. 
                function () {
                    pageInfo = new SP.Publishing.PublishingPageInformation();
                    newPage = pubWeb.addPublishingPage(pageInfo);
                    context.load(newPage);
                    context.executeQueryAsync(
                        function () {

                            // Success callback after adding a new Publishing Page. 
                            // We want to get the actual list item that is represented by the Publishing Page. 
                            listItem = newPage.get_listItem();
                            context.load(listItem);

                            context.executeQueryAsync(



                                                                function () {
                                                                                          var x = web.get_url() + "/Pages/" + listItem.get_fieldValues().FileLeafRef;
                                          alert(x);
                                    var relativeUrl = "/sites/poc/Pages/" + listItem.get_fieldValues().FileLeafRef;
                                    var pageFile = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeUrl);
                                    context.load(pageFile);
                                    var pageItem = pageFile.get_listItemAllFields();
                                    context.load(pageItem);

                                    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {

                                        //change page layout
                                        var itemValue = pageItem.get_item('PublishingPageLayout');
                                        itemValue.set_url(web.get_url() + '/_catalogs/masterpage/' + 'Yaroslav1.aspx');
                                        itemValue.set_description('Some description');

                                        //change title and url of newly created publishing page
                                        pageItem.set_item('PublishingPageLayout', itemValue);
                                        pageItem.set_item('Title', 'NewPage');
                                        pageItem.set_item('FileLeafRef', 'NewPage' + '.aspx');

                                        pageItem.update();
                                        alert('success');
                                    }, function (sender, args) {
                                        alert('Failed to get the PublishingWeba: ' + args.get_message());
                                    });
                                },


                                // Failure callback after getting the actual list item that is  
                                // represented by the Publishing Page. 
                                function (sender, args) {
                                    alert('Failed to get new page: ' + args.get_message());
                                }
                                );
                        },
                        // Failure callback after trying to add a new Publishing Page. 
                        function (sender, args) {
                            alert('Failed to Add Page: ' + args.get_message());
                        }
                        );
                },
                // Failure callback after trying to get the host Web as a PublishingWeb. 
                function (sender, args) {
                    alert('Failed to get the PublishingWeb: ' + args.get_message());
                }
                );
        },
        // Failure callback after trying to load the App Web. 
        function (sender, args) {
            alert('Failed to get the hosting Web: ' + args.get_message());
        });
}




function getQueryStringParameter(urlParameterKey) {

    var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');

    var strParams = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {

        var singleParam = params[i].split('=');

        if (singleParam[0] == urlParameterKey)

            return decodeURIComponent(singleParam[1]);

    }

}
```

Comment: I having the same problem in CSOM. I will write a solution, if I resolve the issue.